# Incremental C++ Analysis in SonarQube

Tags: c++, sonarqube

We are currently implementing a new Continuous Integration system based around SonarQube and whilst things are going well for our Java based projects we are struggling a little with our C++ projects.

The main problem is that building our C++ projects takes over an hour and full static analysis takes 8+ hours, but for CI we need to reduce this to under an hour.

The solution seems to be to use Incremental builds. Using Incremental builds and incremental Static Analysis in Visual Studio we can get the typical build time down to a couple of minutes.

The question is, does SonarQube support Incremental Static analysis of C++ projects so that we don't have to perform a full 8+ hour analysis every time the code changes even slightly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a way to achieve what you are looking for. Since I don't remember the specifics, let's wait for someone else to address that part. Rest assured, you CAN do incremental build with SonarQube.